# Java script confirmation form submit MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Im trying to call the java script confirmation form submit but it skips it. It directly calls the controller even though i want to run first the java script for confirmation.
I dont know what im doing wrong. Still new to JV Scripts.

HTML

```
@model WMS_Web.Models.FileMaintenance.PrincipalModels
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/Script/FileMaintenance/CommonFunction.js")
}
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "PrincipalModel";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Principal</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create","Principal",FormMethod.Post)) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CompanyId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompanyId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <button onclick='functionConfirm("Do you like Football?", function yes() {
         alert("Yes")
      },
      function no() {
         alert("no")
      });'>XXX</button>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back", "ViewPrincipal")
</div>
```

Java Script

```
function functionConfirm(msg, myYes, myNo) {
    var confirmBox = $("#confirm");
    confirmBox.find(".message").text(msg);
    confirmBox.find(".yes,.no").unbind().click(function () {
        confirmBox.hide();
    });
    confirmBox.find(".yes").click(myYes);
    confirmBox.find(".no").click(myNo);
    confirmBox.show();
}
```

Comment: What’s a JV script?

Comment: `<button/>` will submit the form by default, I'd suggest changing it to `<input type="button" />`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add confirmation dialog to a submit button in html5 form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31963401/how-can-i-add-confirmation-dialog-to-a-submit-button-in-html5-form)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create","Principal",FormMethod.Post)) 
{
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   ...
   <input type="submit" name="name" value="Save" onclick="javascript: return SubmitForm();" />
}
```

**Javascript**:

```
function SubmitForm() {
   var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to submit?");
    if (r == false) {
      return false;
    }
    // do something
    return true;       
}
```